# Get "intl-tel-input" mobile number with the country code using PHP than JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, php-7

I have a signup form (PHP & MySql) where visitors can submit their name, email & mobile number. After submission, it goes to the database.

Now I want to add a country code with a dropdown in front of the mobile number, so visitors can select the country they want & enter their mobile number.

For that, I used the "intl-tel-input" from Github. Everything is working fine. but when I try to get the value of a mobile number with country code using PHP's POST or GET method, it's not working. But it works when I try to get the value from JS.

Below is the code of getting a mobile number with country code from JS & it works completely fine.

```
<div class="container">
      <form id="login" onsubmit="process(event)">
        <p>Enter your phone number:</p>
        <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Verify" />
      </form>
      <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none"></div>
      <div class="alert alert-error" style="display: none"></div>
</div>

<script>
    const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#phone");
    const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
      utilsScript:
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
    });

    const info = document.querySelector(".alert-info");
    const error = document.querySelector(".alert-error");

    function process(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const phoneNumber = phoneInput.getNumber();

      info.style.display = "none";
      error.style.display = "none";

      if (phoneInput.isValidNumber()) {
        info.style.display = "";
        info.innerHTML = `Phone number in E.164 format: <strong>${phoneNumber}</strong>`;
      } else {
        error.style.display = "";
        error.innerHTML = `Invalid phone number.`;
      }
    }
  </script>
```

I know I can get data using JS & add it to the database. But is there any way so I can get the mobile number value with country code using the POST method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you passing the final phone number to PHP? In your current example there's only the JS side, please show how you're passing it to the PHP side.

Comment: I am facing difficultly in passing the final value in PHP only, I used to get values using the form submission with POST method. now after form submission, it's calling JS function.

Comment: Ok, see my answer below based on this comment

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reply to my previous comment, the issue is that you used Javascript to validate and correctly format the number and now you need to pass the formatted value back to PHP

You can do this by taking the `phoneNumber` result, placing it back into the input and then submitting the form.

Here's the code

```
<div class="container">
      <form id="login" onsubmit="return process(event)">
        <p>Enter your phone number:</p>
        <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Verify" />
      </form>
      <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none"></div>
      <div class="alert alert-error" style="display: none"></div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/css/intlTelInput.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const phoneInputField = document.querySelector("#phone");
    const phoneInput = window.intlTelInput(phoneInputField, {
      utilsScript:
        "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.8/js/utils.js",
    });

    const info = document.querySelector(".alert-info");
    const error = document.querySelector(".alert-error");

    function process(event) {

      const phoneNumber = phoneInput.getNumber();

      info.style.display = "none";
      error.style.display = "none";

      if (phoneInput.isValidNumber()) {
        info.style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("phone").value=phoneNumber
        return true
        // info.innerHTML = `Phone number in E.164 format: <strong>${phoneNumber}</strong>`;
      } else {
        error.style.display = "";
        error.innerHTML = `Invalid phone number.`;
        return false;
      }
    }
  </script>
```

The changes are:

- the `onsubmit` event of the form now checks for the returned value. If it's false, won't submit, if it's true, will keep submitting
- the `process(event)` function now returns true if the phone number is validated or false if it's not
- if `process(event)` return true, it also edits the `input` containing the phone number with the correctly formatted value

You can of course now switch the form to POST instead of get, change the action etc...

Comment: Now I used the POST method, it's working perfectly fine as expected including warning message, validation &, etc.
Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, if this answered your question remember to mark the answer as correct question to help other people who will find this page in the future.